# SMTP OAuth2 integration for ISV - does each client need a ClientID/Secret or does the ISV need these?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

We are building an integration to send emails via SMTP using OAuth2 security.  Some other OAuth2 integrations we have will use the same ClientID/Secret for all customers connecting our application to their services.

What is best practise with the Google SMTP OAuth2 system?  Do we register our application with Google and embed the ClientID/Secret in the application or should the client be creating one for themselves and entering it into our application?

Answer (score 0):

A project on Google denotes a single application.

An application can have more than one client depending upon the needs of the application.

- desktop app
- web app
- mobile app

the client id and secrete are used to request consent of users of the application to access their data.  As the developer of the application you should be creating the client id and secrete for your application.

as for embedding it that depends on the type of application you are create. What you need to remember is that you are required by Google to keep your client id and secrete secure you should not be giving this out to anyone.  It should only be used by your application.